# How to take multiple input in python for list and tuple by comprehension

Tags: python, list, tuples, multiple-input

How to take multiple input in a single line for tuple and list ?

```
a= list(x = int(input()) for x in range(n)  if x > 0)

''' it has an error , how can I solve it and use similar code for tuple '''
```

Comment: could you give an example input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` on your comprehension, like this:

```py
a = list(filter(lambda x: x>0, (int(input()) for _ in range(n))))
```

For `n = 5` and the input:

```
1
0
3
-10
4
```

it would print:

```
[1, 3, 4]
```